# Umbraco 7 creating multiple copies of templates

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Not sure why but for some reason Umbraco is creating multiple copies of templates, all of which are blank.

Sorry a little vague but haven't got much to go on. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Need more information about what recent changes you did after which you started getting this template copies

Comment: Is this happening when adding NEW templates, or when saving EXISTING ones? Also, which version of v7 are you running please?

Comment: Apologies for slow reply. It seems to be happening when saving existing templates. Am doing most my editing via visual studio. Using v7.4.3.